# How build a regex for this?

Tags: regex

Data:

```
(650 ) 724-6354
(650)  724-6354
(650)724-6354
650 724-6354
650 724 6354
650   724   6354
```

Can anybody please suggest one regex for the above?
I need to detect the 10 digits and represent it like `650-724-6354`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the digits in 3 regex captures:

```
/(\d{3})[ \)]+(\d{3})[ \-]+(\d{4})/
```

Comment: It is so much simplistic and only will works on given strings. And, for more complex separators than parenthesis or dashs? It is an imcomplete solution, considering general purpose validation

Comment: Yes, it is simplistic, but it works for the strings shown in the question. You know, [KISS](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KeepItSimple).

Comment: @tompave : sorry to mention, if I don't want to detect the sequence    6507246354 , what should i do. currently it detects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That regex will work for _any_ digit in strings like the ones in your example. The digit group will then be available in the captures (the parenthesis groups in the regex). If you want to _display_ them with hyphens, then it depends on the language you're using I'm afraid.

Comment: @tompave : thanks for reply. I meant that I forget to mention one more case in my examples that is it should not take into account the sequence 6507246354. Currently it captures this sequence. Can do something to the regex which will work on above example but should not work on the example 6507246354.

Comment: I see. All you need is to swap the `*` for `+`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
 Search: .*(\d{3}).*(\d{3}).*(\d{4})
Replace: \1-\2-\3
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lC6wS1/1)

Answer (score 0):

in PCRE syntax a possible solution could be:

```
/\(?\s*(\d{3})\s*\)?(\s*|-)(\d{3})(\s*|-)(\d{4})/
```

Then, the $1, $3, $5 will contain a total of 10 digits you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is a more complete suggestion, with reduced flaws for more complex sequence of chars.

A simple snippet written in python considering any kind of caracters between groups, returns compontents of each number sequence.

```
import re


def get_components(phone_str):
    rex = re.compile(r"[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})[^\d]*")
    return rex.findall(phone_str)[0]
```

Here is a test code using your example string:

```
test_strs = [
    "650   724   6354",
    "(650 ) 724-6354",
     "(650)  724-6354",
     "(650)724-6354",
     "650 724-6354",
     "650 724 6354",
     "650   724   6354",
]
print(["%s-%s-%s"%get_components(p) for p in test_strs])
```